# regarding FLOT CHARTS API Error :Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, flot, bar-chart

hi this is my code for the FLOT charts API. I am getting the graph but I am getting the above mentioned error. Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    var a1 = [
        [0, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 6],
        [3, 9],
        [4, 5]
    ];
    var a2 = [
        [0, 4],
        [1, 5],
        [2, 1],
        [3, 7],
        [4, 7]
    ];
    var data = [{
        label: "Pre Transformation",
        data: a1
    }, {
        label: "Post Transformation",
        data: a2
    }];

    $.plot($("#consolidate1"), data, {
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.13,
                order: 1,
                align: "center"
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            ticks: [
                [0, "Overall"],
                [1, "SEA"],
                [2, "INDIA"],
                [3, "NEA"],
                [4, "PZ"]
            ],
            tickLength: 0
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true,
            labelMargin: 15
        },

        valueLabels: {
            show: false
        }
    });
});


var previousPoint = null,
    previousLabel = null;

function showTooltip(x, y, color, contents) {
    $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'none',
        top: y - 40,
        left: x - 120,
        border: '2px solid ' + color,
        padding: '3px',
            'font-size': '9px',
            'border-radius': '5px',
            'background-color': '#fff',
            'font-family': 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
        opacity: 0.9
    }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
}

$("#consolidate1").on("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
        if ((previousLabel != item.series.label) || (previousPoint != item.dataIndex)) {
            previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
            previousLabel = item.series.label;
            $("#tooltip").remove();

            var x = item.dataIndex;
            var y = item.datapoint[1];
            var color = item.series.color;

            //console.log(item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label);               

            showTooltip(item.pageX,
            item.pageY,
            color,
                "<strong>" + item.series.label + "</strong><br>" + item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label + ":  <strong>" + y + "</strong>");
        }
    } else {
        $("#tooltip").remove();
        previousPoint = null;
    }
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <p>Yearly Energy Consumption</p>
    <div id="consolidate1" style="width:500px;height:300px;"></div>
</div>
```

Code in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24Dqr/).

I am not able to figure out why this error is coming up.

Comment: Added fiddle, but can't reproduce the error in the fiddle.

Comment: Ran it stand-alone for you on my own computer. Still, I can't reproduce the error either.

Comment: btw: consider using the stack plugin (see this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24Dqr/1/) for an example)

Comment: but I am facing the error again.The error is thrown from JS part. it is line 2907 in jquery.flot.js. The exact working is in the fiddle shared by you Raidri. Please tell me all the js to be included for this module.

Comment: for the stack plugin you only need the normal `jquery.flot.js` and `http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.stack.js`. Then add `stack: true` under `series` in your options.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either; what browser & version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I got the similar error ... on debugging i found that the error was pointing to "~/float.js"
.... then later i checked my code, there was another chart that i was trying to plot and for that chart i commented out the Html part of the chart.. so i was getting the above mentioned error.

The way i fixed is : commented out the 
     $.plot() 
for other chart.

Hope this might help someone!